# AVCaptureSession startRunning makes AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer black first

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

Recently, I am developing QR Code Recognition on iPhone. I use AVFoundation framework. I use **AVCaptureSession** to connect with AVCaptureDeviceInput and AVCaptureMetadataOutput and use **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer** to display.
The issue is that When AVCaptureSession startRunning, **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer first becomes black and gradually return to normal.** The issue is a poor user experience. Now I use GCD's dispatch_after() to solve this issue temporarily. I know is there any other solutions.
Because AVCaptureSession's startRunning method is time-consuming, I call startRunning() on the background thread. I use a loading view to make user wait for the AVCaptureSession start. I observe "AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification" notification. But when the notification posted the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer still black first and gradually return to normal.

```
dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, ^{
            [_avSession startRunning];
            CGRect rectOfInterest = [_previewLayer metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:_config.rectOfInterest];
            _metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = rectOfInterest;
        }
    }
});

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(avSessionDidStartRunning) name:AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Have somebody any solution for that? I've tried set clear background for layers and views but the "problem" still happening.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. First few frames are very dark and it gets normal after it. I didn't find any other solution apart from `dispatch_after()`....

Comment: Hey! Did you find any solution for that problem? I'm having the same issue...